# node command and file name

Tags: node.js, command

I was working on a project and launched my node server with a mistake inside the command.

I typed: `node index;Js`

Surprisingly, this worked and launched the script correctly, even though my script name is `index.js`

Why did this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running a node/npm start, it will expect a js file. The semi-colon acts as normal and ends the line of code there. Much like how you can import modules and leave off the trailing .js